# RestRequest error "Method Not Allowed" on Android Device or Simulator

Tags: c#, maui

he class below is from a .net 7.0 MAUI app and it retrieves data from a REST API.

When I run the program from "Windows Machine" it works fine. However, when I run the program from and android simulator or Android phone it doesn’t work.

I call the method “GetPilots()” which then call “GetToken()” to get a token from the RESTApi. This part works fine. I verified that the has been gotten successfully.

The method continues executing and at line “RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);” I get the following the following error "Method Not Allowed" at line"

```
public class PilotSQLServerRepository 
    {
        public string GetToken() {
             var client = new RestClient("https://<domain>/");
            var request = new RestRequest("Login", Method.Post);

            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
             var result = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
             var token = result["result"].Value<string>();

            return token;
        }

        public void GetPilots() {

            string token = GetToken();
            var client = new RestClient("https://<domain>/");
            try {
                var request = new RestRequest("Pilot", Method.Get);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + token.Trim((char)34));
                var body = @"";
                request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

                RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);       // On and android phone or simulator this line returns
                                                                       // METHODE NOT ALLOWED. On a Windows Machine the
                                                                       // the class returns the correct result from the RESTApi
                var pilot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Pilot>>(response.Content);
               // Console.WriteLine("Code = " + response.StatusCode);
               Console.ReadKey();
                
              //  var result = await Task.FromResult(new List<Pilot>());
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
               
            }
        }
    }
```

I am stumped since the project works as a "Windows Machine" and not on "Android".

Comment: Please show the **entire** message part of the error, not just the first few words. There are a few things that you should fix as well. `Execute()` is a blocking call and you should use `await ExecuteAsync()` instead inside an `async` method using the [async-await](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model) pattern. Currently, you create a new instance of `RestClient` for every method call, which is wasteful and can cause unwanted side effects. Consider making the `RestClient` a member variable and use that instance in the methods.

Comment: What user action results in this method being called? If this is in code that runs when a page is about to be displayed, then as a test, instead make the call when some [button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button?view=net-maui-7.0) is pushed by user. This is an easy place to use `async/await` correctly. (or using your current code, to simplify what is happening in maui at same time.) See code example in that link. If can't get that to work, then there may be some `permissions` problem in your Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the line below fixed the problem.

```
request.AddParameter("text/plain", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code under platforms -> Android -> MainApplication.cs

```
[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
```

[check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqYK0.png)